# Websockets with Play Framework 2.x - Java - 500 Error

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am trying to incorporate Websockets in my Play app.
My route file is as below:

```
GET     /login                              controllers.Application.login()
POST    /login                              controllers.Application.authenticate()
GET     /logout                             controllers.Application.logout()

GET     /loggedin               controllers.Presencelanding.loggedInSocket()

GET     /loggedin                            controllers.Presencelanding.loggedIn()
```

I  want to create a websocket as soon as user is redirected to this /loggedin page

Now in my Controller presenceLanding I have

```
 public static Result loggedIn(){ 
   ..... blah ....blah}


 public static WebSocket loggedInSocket() {
 try {
        final Http.Session session = session();
        String username = session(AppConstants.USERNAME);
        connection = getConnection(username);
        connection =  XMPPConnectionHandler.performLogin(    
                    xmppLogin.getLoggedinuser().getUsername(),
                    xmppLogin.getLoggedinuser().getPassword(),connection);
        getAllData();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return new WebSocket() {
        public void onReady(WebSocket.In in, WebSocket.Out out) {
            System.out.println("ready");
            in.onMessage(new F.Callback() {
                public void invoke(String event) {
                    System.out.println(event);
                }

                @Override
                public void invoke(Object a) throws Throwable {
                    System.out.println(a);

                }
            });

            in.onClose(new F.Callback0() {
                public void invoke() {
                    System.out.println("Disconnected");
                }
            });

                           out.write(loggedin.render(xmppLogin,completedChallenges,
                           pendingSentFromMeChal,pendingForMeChal,unseen));
        }
    };
}
```

From my javascript on client I have :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
  getWebSocket();
});

function getWebSocket() {
        var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000/loggedInSocket");
}
```

However when I add the websocket returning function in my routes file I get the error below:
Cannot use a method returning play.mvc.WebSocket[?0] as an Handler

If I remove this line and retry this I get a Javascript console error while trying to setup the websocket:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9000/loggedInSocket' failed: Unexpected response code: 500

QS2: also How do i  update html using same websocket ?

QS 3: There are a lot of posts about the using Iteratees etc for websockets with scala. Is there a parallel for java as well..

Appreciate any help.Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mike  I have updated the question

Comment: at QS2 - your websocket message can contains just a 'signal' for JS, which after receiving will perform common AJAX call in the background receive updated data and will refresh the view

Answer (score 1):

Change your routes to:

```
GET     /login                              controllers.Application.login()
POST    /login                              controllers.Application.authenticate()
GET     /logout                             controllers.Application.logout()

GET     /loggedInSocket                     controllers.Presencelanding.loggedInSocket()

GET     /loggedin                           controllers.Presencelanding.loggedIn()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers .
I could solve this by adding following line in routes file:

```
GET     /loggedin/loggedInSocket                 controllers.Presencelanding.loggedInSocket()
```